# Получить дочерний объект с ключом из объектов массива react

Tags: reactjs, react-hook

У меня есть во такой хук, содержащий объект в массиве. Сам объект содержит дочерние объекты с ключами:

```
const [Value, setValue] = useState([
      {
        Item1: [
          {
            SubItem11: [{test_key1: "text", test_key2: "another text"}],
            SubItem12: [{test_key1: "text", test_key2: "another text"}]
          }
        ],
        Item2: [
          {
            SubItem21: [{test_key1: "text", test_key2: "another text"}],
            SubItem22: [{test_key1: "text", test_key2: "another text"}]
          }
        ]
      }
])
```

Подскажите пожалуйста, как я могу получить все с помощью `map`. И так же, могли бы вы показать пример доступа только к конкретному ключу объекта? Например, как получить доступ только к `SubItem12`?

Спасибо!

Comment: Хука нет, ключа нет, нифига не понятно, а реакт вообще ни на что не влияет.

Comment: > "Хука нет" - useState это что по вашему?

Comment: Что ты собрался делать, используя такой стейт?

Comment: @ksa, я просто хочу отобразить все `test_key1` и `test_key2` в `Value`, используя метод `map`. А так же, получить `test_key1` и `test_key2` только из `SubItem12`.

Comment: А ничего что там массив на массиве сидит и массивом погоняет? :) Но тебе просто нужен тот список?

Comment: > "массив на массиве сидит и массивом погоняет" - это и вызвало для меня трудность. На самом деле, я хотел бы посмотреть два примера:  **1** Получить все `test_key1` и `test_key2` и **2** Получить `test_key1` и `test_key2` только из `SubItem12`, как писал выше

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> можете показать еще один пример того, как получить все конечные ключи?

Например вот так это можно сделать...

```js
//
function App() {
  const [value, setValue] = React.useState([
    {
      Item1: [
        {
          SubItem11: [{test_key1: "text", test_key2: "another text"}],
          SubItem12: [
            {test_key1: "text1", test_key2: "another text1"},
            {test_key1: "text2", test_key2: "another text2"},
          ]
        }
      ],
      Item2: [
        {
          SubItem21: [{test_key1: "text", test_key2: "another text"}],
          SubItem22: [{test_key1: "text", test_key2: "another text"}]
        }
      ]
    }
  ])
  const a = value.reduce(line, [])
  return <section>
    {a.map((o, i) => <p key={i}>{o.test_key1} - {o.test_key2}</p>)}
  </section>
}
//
function line(arr, o) {
  const a = Object.values(o).flat().map(o => Object.values(o).flat()).flat()
  return [...arr, ...a]
} 

const domContainer = document.querySelector('#like_button_container');
const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(domContainer);
root.render(<App />);
```

```html
<div id="like_button_container"></div>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@18/umd/react.development.js" crossorigin></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@18/umd/react-dom.development.js" crossorigin></script>
```

Comment: Спасибо большое!

Answer (score 1):

> Получить test_key1 и test_key2 только из SubItem12

Для такой задачи твой стейт максимально неудобен... :(

Но вот такой вариант можно из него сварганить.

```js
//
function App() {
  const [value, setValue] = React.useState([
    {
      Item1: [
        {
          SubItem11: [{test_key1: "text", test_key2: "another text"}],
          SubItem12: [
            {test_key1: "text1", test_key2: "another text1"},
            {test_key1: "text2", test_key2: "another text2"},
          ]
        }
      ],
      Item2: [
        {
          SubItem21: [{test_key1: "text", test_key2: "another text"}],
          SubItem22: [{test_key1: "text", test_key2: "another text"}]
        }
      ]
    }
  ])
  const a = value.reduce(line, [])
  return <section>
    {a.map((o, i) => <p key={i}>{o.test_key1} - {o.test_key2}</p>)}
  </section>
}
//
function line(arr, o) {
  const a = o.Item1.map(o => o.SubItem12).flat()
  return [...arr, ...a]
} 

const domContainer = document.querySelector('#like_button_container');
const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(domContainer);
root.render(<App />);
```

```html
<div id="like_button_container"></div>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@18/umd/react.development.js" crossorigin></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@18/umd/react-dom.development.js" crossorigin></script>
```

Comment: спасибо за ответ, но к сожалению, я не могу изменить структуру стейта

Comment: @rabbit, так я структуру стейта и не менял... Какой он у тебя был - такой и остался.

Comment: сорян. я похоже уже переработал ))

Comment: можете показать еще один пример того, как получить все конечные ключи? это тоже важно